# Override django user with AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have override the default User model in my app with `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Here is the user model I want to use in my app, which is tied closely to a legacy database:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    normalized_email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

However, django complains that fields such as `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. are not provided. Is there a way to remove some of the existing fields in the `User` model? Or does specifying a custom user model only allow you to **add** additional fields on top of that? Is there a simple way to delete them, or do I basically have to add those fields (and ignore them) to our existing database in order to be able to use django with it?

Answer (score 3):

`AbstractUser` is for when you want to add additional fields to Django's defaults. Use [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) if you don't want all those fields.

Comment: thanks, and the only requirement here is I specify what the `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` is, or are there any other defaults I need to add?

Comment: Read the documentation that @Alasdair provided in the link for AbstractBaseUser, that'll tell you what you have to provide and how to make things optional. You must also supply `EMAIL_FIELD` and `REQUIRED_FIELDS`.

Comment: Also note that you might want to add the `PermissionsMixin` into your model if you want to keep the Django permission model with Groups and user permissions. Best thing is to look at Django's source code for how `AbstractUser` is implemented